Update rest of the bar colors except clicked bar dynamically in highcharts, default first bar should be selected


By default total row (first one should be highlighted) rest all with opacity 0.2
If I click on the any of the bars, rest of the bars opacity should become 0.2 except the clicked one


Does this answer your question? Highlight Single Bar/Column in Highcharts on load

@JonathanStellwag No this is not what I was looking for.

what are you looking for? In the question/answer they query a specific chart row and update its color. This should also be possible for transparency in your case (and other css manipulations).

Hi @JonathanStellwag I solved this by manipulating the series.data array by adding transparency to color based on the state/clicked bar id. If the selected bar ID equals the bar ID while creating the series.data array, i don't add the opacity to color. What do you think about this approach?

You can achieve the result by using Highcharts API, only by using the point selection feature.
For example:
const data = [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175];

const processedData = data.map((value, index) => ({
  y: value,
  selected: index === 0,
  opacity: 0.2
}));

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    type: 'bar',
    allowPointSelect: true,
    data: processedData,
    color: 'blue',
    states: {
      select: {
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'blue'
      }
    }
  }]
});


Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uz280o9b/
API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.allowPointSelect
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.states.select
